# MongoDb aggregation combining objects by key into array

Tags: mongodb

I have a json document where one array has multiple objects. I want to combine all objects into array having the same key.

I want to perform such conversion using MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

Input:

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "65e6afb50f89ab48c027c54f",
    "items": [
      {
        "A": {
          "id": "ci33985107542",
          "sku": "2519438"
        }
      },
      {
        "A": {
          "id": "ci34045151326",
          "sku": "2517213"
        }
      },
      {
        "B": {
          "id": "ci34045151457",
          "sku": "2261539"
        }
      },
      {
        "B": {
          "id": "ci34045151509",
          "sku": "2302283"
        }
      },
      {
        "B": {
          "id": "ci34045151436",
          "sku": "2520098"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "65e6afb50f89ab48c027c54f",
    "items": [
      {
        "A": [
          {
            "id": "ci33985107542",
            "sku": "2519438"
          },
          {
            "id": "ci34045151326",
            "sku": "2517213"
          }
        ],
        "B": [
          {
            "id": "ci34045151457",
            "sku": "2261539"
          },
          {
            "id": "ci34045151509",
            "sku": "2302283"
          },
          {
            "id": "ci34045151436",
            "sku": "2520098"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm quite new to MongoDB aggregation pipeline. I was going through some documents and looks like it can be done using $group, but haven't able to achieve that yet.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Using dynamic values as field name is generally considered as anti-pattern and should be avoided. Also, in your expected result, you are going to keep a bloat object as a singleton element in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Side note: A well-designed document structure could save you time and better performance in querying.*

**Solution 1**

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `items` array into multiple documents.
2. `$set` - Convert the `items` document to an array of documents with `k` and `v` fields.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id` and `item.k` and add the first `v` document into `items` array.
4. `$group` - Group by `_id._id` and push the converted to key-value pair document into the `items` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $objectToArray: "$items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        key: {
          $first: "$items.k"
        }
      },
      items: {
        $push: {
          $first: "$items.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      items: {
        $push: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [
              {
                k: "$_id.key",
                v: "$items"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1@ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1i3EYPtiw_h)

---

**Solution 2**

Another solution is slightly complex and does not use the `$unwind` and `$group` operators.

1. `$set` - Iterate each element and convert it into an array of the documents with `k` and `v` fields in the `items` array.
2. `$set` - Combine nested (dimensional) arrays from the previous stage into a single (level) array.
3. `$set` - Iterating each key from the `flattedItems` array (`$map`), converting the array into objects (`$arrayToObject`) by performing grouping/filtering based on `k` fields and retrieving the `v` field.
4. `$unset` - Remove the `flattedItems` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      flattedItems: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            $objectToArray: "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      flattedItems: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$flattedItems",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $setUnion: "$flattedItems.k"
          },
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              [
                {
                  k: "$$this",
                  v: {
                    $map: {
                      input: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$flattedItems",
                          as: "item",
                          cond: {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$this",
                              "$$item.k"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      in: "$$this.v"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "flattedItems"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBRiGWB8_VK)

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I will prefer method 1.
One question, what if there more fields other than items. I just want to output them as they are without explicitly listing them in $group like you did with _id